# Bibtex warning and errors

Tags: bibtex

I have problem in running Bibtex
first I have to know if i have Pine et al,(1999) in tex, is it correct to write `\cite{Pine1999}` or I have to write `\cite{Pine,Winn,Wrigh1999}`
which one is correct?

Second, in first running of Bibtex I have some empty spaces, then I removed them, but after saving and running again I still receive the same error

Third, I have all cites in my Mendeley and I run the bib file first but receive the blew warning saying that the  database entry for some cite did not find? I am a student and this is my first experience with LaTeX please kindly help me. many thanks
here it is the error and warning:

I'm skipping whatever remains of this command

```
White space in argument---line 70 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \citation{Saeednia,Goodarzi
 :                             2013}

I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 102 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {model1-num-names}

I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 103 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {model1a-num-names}

I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 104 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {model2-names.bst}

I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 105 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {agsm}

I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I couldn't open database file figure/bib.bib
---line 106 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \bibdata{figure/bib
 :                    }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command

I found no database files---while reading file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Tsaur"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Chiu"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Wang2006"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Solomon2016"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Schmitt1999"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "liou2011"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "lee"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "chang2012"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "chao2015"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "smilanski2009"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Guest1994"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Guest1995"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Oliver1980"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Dick"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Basue1994"

Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Lora"
```

Comment: This seems very similar to your earlier question. Cite keys should never contain spaces or commas or anything like that. They need to match exactly the key that is in your `.bib` file. So you need to be able to actually see the `.bib` file that Mendelay produces to know what the correct thing to put in the `\cite` command. We can't help you with that, since we don't know what your `.bib` file looks like. You also seem to have more than one `\bibliographystyle` command in your document. This is not a good idea. Please edit your earlier question to answer the questions asked in the comments.

Comment: Tnx, but as I told in second part I removed all empty spaces but again I received that errors, and another question is in case of having 2 or there authors in writing /\cite I am not allowed to put commas and separate the family name of authors? many thanks

Comment: We can't tell you what should go into your `\cite` commands without seeing what your `.bib` file entries look like.  What goes in the `\cite` command can have little or no connection to the actual authors in the `.bib` file.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://libguides.rhul.ac.uk/c.php?g=380520&p=4650349. Also here: https://blog.mendeley.com/2011/10/25/howto-use-mendeley-to-create-citations-using-latex-and-bibtex/ These links imply that the default citation key is simply `AuthorYear`. Since I've never used Mendelay, I have no idea what it does with multiple authors; it could just do `FirstAuthorYear`, so any multiauthor work would not have multiple authors in the key.

Comment: If you look at the image in the second link above, that seems to be the case. The sample `.bib` entry view shows a multi-author article Qiu, Zhang, Zhang and Chen (2010), and the cite key is just `Qiu2010`. So you would put `\cite{Qiu2010}` in your LaTeX document.

Comment: Many many thanks